# JEditable and Selects

Tags: jeditable

I have the following html:

```
<div id=country>United States</div>
```

I am using JEditable to for inline editing of the country div using a select box and im using the Codeigniter framework. I load the select via loadURL as an array with the id and description eg.

array['1'] = 'United States'
array['2'] = 'United Kingdom'

I select my new selection and call an update function within the Controller which then calls the DB update function in the Model and updates the table with the new country id. 
The country_id field in the members table gets updated with a value of '2' for the United Kingdom.

I then echo back returning the value to the View. This all works perfectly but JEditable then displays the value being '2' rather than the description back in the Div.

The issue is that I pass the id and not the description and its the id that gets returned and displayed. A solution would be to do a table lookup in the model to get the description and then return the description rather than the id but this method performs another DB select for a description that is already in the view.
JEditable should just show the new description once complete for a select box rather than its default of the id or 'the tooltip if you dont return back the value.

Does anyone have a good solution for this? Your thoughts and advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Echo back the value you want to be displayed on the webpage. Meaning instead of echoing "2" echo "United Kingdom".